# ORA 01722 : Dealing with invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am dealing with some data quality issues. I would like to remove all the dots and replace dot with comma in the end and replace negative in the end to front.
Below are the examples:

70.693.271.273,20- convert to -70693271273,20
1.312.871.286.870- convert to -1312871286,870

For the first case 70.693.271.273,20- I am using the below syntax which gives me results -70693271273,20

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT("/BIC/ISMVALUE", '\.') >= 1
AND REGEXP_COUNT("/BIC/ISMVALUE", ',') = 1 THEN
to_number(REPLACE(TRIM(BOTH '-' FROM TRIM("/BIC/ISMVALUE")), '.', '') * (-1))
ELSE TO_NUMBER(TRIM("/BIC/ISMVALUE")) END oprl_value
```

[image]
Similarly I would like to get same format results for case 2.
Can you please help on how to deal with second case 1.312.871.286.870- ?
Thanks

Comment: Are the numbers always negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the group and decimal separators as part of the `to_number()` call. If the numbers are always negative then you can include that too:

```
to_number(
    "/BIC/ISMVALUE", 
    '999G999G999G999G999D99MI',
    'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=,.'
  )
```

If you have a mix of positive and negative numbers then the `MI` element will cause an error; if the positive numbers have a trailing `+` then you could use `S` instead of `MI`, but that seems unlikely. So instead you can handle negativity separately via a case expression, and strip the minus sign during conversion:

```
case when substr("/BIC/ISMVALUE", -1) = '-' then -1 else 1 end
*
to_number(
    rtrim("/BIC/ISMVALUE", '-'),
    '999G999G999G999G999D99',
    'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=,.'
  )
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1eb43693697f41295297f8b87ce4d4a4)

It's then up to your client or application to decide how to format that number for display - including which character to use as a decimal separator.

Comment: Thanks But when i execute whole query then i get this error : ORA-1722: Invalid number. It seems that the sql is still having issue with VARCHAR

Comment: Your question only shows strings in that format, and the fiddle shows it working for your example values (and an additional positive value, for the second expression). If you have multiple formats then you'll need to figure out which format to apply to each value - possibly still by matching with regular expressions, but possibly by writing a function that tries multiple formats in turn until it finds one that doesn't error. Without knowing more about your data, it's hard to say what you should do.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple replace and concatenation

```
SELECT '-' || REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(your_value),'.',','),'-','') AS oprl_value
```